# Generate layers based on feature values

Tags: arcgis-server, layers, features, map-service, dynamic

First of all, I am very new to the GIS world, so bear with me if the question is stupid.

I am using ArcGIS and here's what I try to accomplish:

I have a feature class (let's call it Areas) storing polygons with some extra data (name, id etc). 
If I create a layer and publish this as a MapService, I can use it in my .NET application (or in the browser via REST) to display a layer containing all the Areas.
In my app, I can even do filtering (with LayerDefinitions) to only display a certain area at a time.

What I would like to do is (within the ArcGIS server, so that it is reflected on all clients) have one layer for each of the Areas in the feature table.

So the REST directory in a browser would display:

Layers:

- Areas

  - Area 1
  - Area 2
  - Area 3

And I would be able to see the same structure in a TOC and control visibility on/off on each of the Areas.

The "projection" of turning every feature into a separate layer must be dynamic, so that if I add another Area, it would automatically become a new layer (IE no configuration or republishing the MapService).

Is this possible within ArcMap? Can I code it in Python and have it run inside the MapService somehow? Do I have to write a SOE ? Or isn't it possible at all (only on the client side)?

Comment: We can add each feature as different layer via Python but how would you reflect the newly added features on REST end as new layer without republishing? I suggest that you should write code to display custom TOC to show each feature as layer.

Comment: But could you have the Python republish the service automatically then? It's not a requirement that I shouldn't have to republish, but I shouldn't have to republish manually.
If I can have a Python script running on the server that would pick up changes to the feature-table, add a new layer, and then overwrite the service it would be fine.

Comment: Yes, republishing via Python is doable but I believe that you are planning to add new features from your application through REST end. If this is the case then you have to call another GPTask which add the new feature as layer and then republish it, which is a way expensive task if you are adding multiple polygon features from multiple users.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a good solution, I agree.
Is it possible to manipulate the "default" TOC then? For clients that I don't control myself?
So that when you view the REST directory, and click "View in: ArcGIS.com Map" it will display the custom TOC ?

Comment: You can control TOC behavior in you application but not on mapserver REST end or "View in: ArcGIS.com Map". There it will show as one layer but on your application you can read names and mimic it as a layer.